# Get the total number of nodes and counting nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, count, xmlnode

Is it possible to get the total number of XML nodes?

Also, how does one do a for-statement with XSLT?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to count the node of you XML you could use count(object/node) and it will be something like this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(/root/*)"/>
```

The instruction above will let you know how many child nodes does your root node has

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/element-you-wanna-loop" >
    <!-- Do something with your nodes here -->    
</xsl:for-each>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: How would I get the current node number?

Comment: you should replace the /root for you current node if you're in that node you could just use the count(*)